# Available units / simultaneous calls for service

Tags: excel

I'm struggling with a vehicle availability problem in Excel. I need to track overlapping date-time ranges in a way that will show me how often more than two incidents are going on at the same time.

To put it differently, if I have only two units available to handle transports and I am given a list of start and end times of historical transports, how many times would I miss a transport on that list (how often are more then two transports going on at the same time)?

For example, if I start with `2` units and a call for service comes in, now I have `1` unit available. If another call comes in before the previous call ends, I now have `0` units available. If I get another call for service before either unit returns to service, I will miss a call.

How can I evaluate a list of date-time intervals in Excel to determine which calls I would have missed?

I've tried using `=SUMPRODUCT((A2<=$B$2:$B$3584)*(B2>=$A$2:$A$3584))` but this isn't quite right and I can't quite figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Please try (where I have assumed as a start point 1/1/15 has both units available):

```
=IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,A:A))>F2,1,0)+IF(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(F2,C:C))>F2,1,0)
```

[image: SO29810325 example]